# Generating random words in PHP

Tags: php, passwords

This is my code, but I am getting an error called "Undefined function get_random_word". Help.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($_POST['email']));


        $new_password = get_random_word(6, 13);
        if($new_passowrd==false){
            throw new Exception('Oops! ');
        }

        $rand_number = rand(0,999);
        $new_password .= $rand_number;
        mysqli_select_db($connect,"membership");
        $result = "update users set password = sha1('".$new_password."')
        where email = '".$email."'";
        $q = mysqli_query($connect,$result) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        if(!q){
            throw new Exception('Oops!');
        }
        else
        {
            return $new_password;
        }
    }


?>
```

Can someone help me create it. I want to generate a random password for the user. Thanks

Comment: Where is `get_random_word()` declared?

Comment: That's unsurprising, since the function `get_random_word()` is not defined. Where did you get this code from?

Comment: sometimes errors are too explicit.

Comment: did you delete your question? Why? Couldn't it have been interesting for someone else with the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

get_random_word is not a standard php function. Apparently, get_random_word() is in the user_auth_fns.php5 library.

http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10331068.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a function called `get_random_word`. You can't call a function you haven't defined.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `get_random_word()` is not a standard PHP function.

[Somebody else with the same problem](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10331068.html), and how to proceed.

And once you've solved the above, you have a typo that will prevent your code from proceeding...

```
if($new_passowrd==false){
  throw new Exception('Oops! ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error tells you that `get_random_word()` has not been declared.  You either need to find out where it went, or create it.  `get_random_word()` is not a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the function

```
$new_password = get_random_word(6, 13);
```

but not defined the function